# How to read data from xml and get the data from the class instance

Tags: c#, xml, class

I am new in c# (for Windows App) and I am trying to understand an example that I found in the web.

There is a class:

```
public class Person
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    int age;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstname; }
        set { firstname = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastname; }
        set { lastname = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }
}
```

And a Code that reads data from XML and binds it to a listbox:

```
string peopleXMLPath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Assets/PeopleData.xml");
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(peopleXMLPath);

var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("person")
           where (int)query.Element("age") == 27
           select new Person
           {
               FirstName = (string)query.Element("firstname"),
               LastName = (string)query.Element("lastname"),
               Age = (int)query.Element("age")
           };
listBox.ItemsSource = data;
```

But how can I get (for example) the FirstName into a string variable to use it in TextBox.text ? And how do I movenext in the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ queries return `IEnumerable<something>`, in your case `IEnumerable<Person>`. You can iterate the result to get each value.

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.FirstName);
    // or in console app
    //Console.WriteLine(item.FirstName);
}
```